# How to reinitialize i-mac 2007 OS X 10.4

Tags: macos

i am trying to reset the i-mac from 2007 OS X 10.4. with command plus R or alt.  These commands are not working, the computer restarts and do let me get to disc utility.  Is there something i can do ?  Is there anyone out there that knows and is willing to share their knowledge about doing this with command plus S mode ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "initialize" look like? I've answered as if you want to wipe and reinstall the OS or repartition the boot drive assuming it's broken or compromised. Please ask a follow on question or edit your main post if I guessed wrongly about initialize. Recover is not going to work no matter what so I wanted to get that out as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Recovery isn't going to be programmed into that old of a Mac. Similarly the recovery HD isn't available with OS older than Lion.

You need to boot from the 10.4 installer or bring another bootable volume with MacOS on it to that Mac to work on it.

I suppose what "intiailize" means to you will govern if single user mode is of any help at all.